# Can I build and archive react native app for ios in debug mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

As title says, I want to build and archive a react native app for ios, but I want the .ipa file to be in debug mode. I've set the Build configuration to Debug in the scheme when building the app, but it's not working.

Comment: Actually, you seem to be able to do it by setting configuration for Archive to Debug, but there seems to be other issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. Debug mode is designed specifically in order for you to *not* archive it.

Comment: Ok, but then point 2 at https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device doesn't make much sense: "Building an app for distribution in the App Store requires using the Release scheme in Xcode. Apps built for Release will automatically disable the in-app Developer menu, which will prevent your users from inadvertently accessing the menu in production". Why is it necessary if it happens automatically?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, if your build type is set to debugging, you cannot archive your project directly. However, you still have the option to run your project on a simulator or a real device for testing purposes.

It's important to note that if your app is in release mode, you can debug it using the Safari Develop Tab. This feature allows you to inspect and debug web views and JavaScript code running within your app.

I hope this information is helpful to you and anyone who may be searching for solutions related to archiving projects on the developer.apple site.